# Regex to match every question on question bank

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a quiz bank with 150 quizzes and i want to use nodejs and regex to extract every question separatedly.

Every question should start with its number, that could be 1 until a tree digit number (150 e.g)

```
3 - FGV
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative
4 - FSV
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative
...
150 - FTB
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative
```

And should end before the new question starts, so i tried using this code above:

```
        data.match(/(?!^)[0-9]{1,3} - ([^\\]+?)[0-9]{1,3} - /).forEach((element) => {
        console.log("found");
     });
```

The problem is that it doesnt match every question block, like 1 until 2 starts, then 2 until 3 starts and keep going.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/OVXTb0/1) what you want?

Comment: The problem with `/(?!^)[0-9]{1,3} - ([^\\]+?)[0-9]{1,3} - /` is not that it *"doesnt match every question block"* - it matches nothing at all. Can you explain what you had in mind when you wrote that expression, because I have trouble guessing what you were going for there. The expression makes no sense to me.

Comment: @raina77ow thank you, it worked perfectly for what i wanted!

Comment: @AcidStormer Glad to help; should I put this into an answer - for you to accept, but also for other users to see?

Answer (score 1):

How about splitting at the start of a question:

```
data.split(/(?=^\d+ - )/gm)
```

This finds 3 blocks from your input:

1.

```
3 - FGV
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative
```

2. 

```
4 - FSV
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative
...
```

3. 

```
150 - FTB
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative
```

Splitting using a zero-width look-ahead `(?=...)` allows you to keep the separator as part of the result. Otherwise `.split()` would remove the separators from the input string, but since look-aheads have a width of zero, the string stays intact.

Comment: If i have a question that starts with:
2 - HTS - SP
Should i change the split to only match numbers{1,3} - ?

Comment: @AcidStormer I'm not sure why that would be necessary?

Comment: Using that code shouldnt it match "2 - HTS -" as a split?

Comment: @AcidStormer It should. If it does not, the `2` is not at the start of the line. Going from your example, all question numbers are at the start of a new line, so that's what the expression above looks for.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/o82GqZ/1 - it would split at every match marker. If you type e.g. a space in front of the `2`, the match marker at that line would go away.

Answer (score 0):

Using `(?!^)[0-9]{1,3} -`  to assert that the line does not start with 1-3 digits means that it is not mandatory in the data.

What you might do is match it to make sure that it is there and capture all following lines in a group that do not start with that pattern using the negative lookahead.

```
^\d{1,3} - .*((?:\n(?!\d{1,3} - ).*)+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltFssa/1)

```js
const regex = /^\d{1,3} - .*((?:\n(?!\d{1,3} - ).*)+)/gm;
const str = `3 - FGV
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative
4 - FSV
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative
...
150 - FTB
Question description
A - Alternative
B - Alternative
C - Alternative
D - Alternative`;

console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1].trim()));
```